# Implementing a spinner causes program crash and

Tags: android, spinner

So, my group is attempting to create a simple Android program to help guide people through buildings. We are attempting to display the results of the search inside of a Spinner, but unfortunately, the program crashes whenever the spinner is initialized. We know that the code works up to the initialization of the Spinner. Can anyone help to diagnose our issue?

Relevant function code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Here goes the code for the searching of the building in the database file.

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String building = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message = "Search results for \"" + building + "\"";

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setText(message);

    InputStream buildinginfo = null;
    try {
        buildinginfo = getResources().getAssets().open("namelist.txt");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader myDIS = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buildinginfo));

    //you've now got an instance of BufferedReader called myDIS

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int x = -1;
    String conglomerate = "";

    for(int i=0;i<101;i++){
    try {
        String something = myDIS.readLine();
        x = something.indexOf(building);
        if(x>-1){
            list.add(something);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
           }


    for(int i=0 ; i < (list.size()-1) ; i++) {
        String display = list.get(i).substring(5);
        conglomerate = conglomerate+display+"\n";
    }
    setContentView(textView);
    //Add Spinner 
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This gives these errors in LogCat.

```
07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{iefx.testing.myapp/iefx.testing.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at iefx.testing.myapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:83)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

07-16 00:19:47.951: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is line 83 of `DisplayMessageActivity`? Some object on that line is null and you are trying to access a member variable or a method on it.

Comment: You have not inflated the view that holds spinner1. What layout file are you referring to?

Comment: @Karakuri That is "spinner.setAdapter(adapter);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView()` and passing in a TextView. You probably want to pass in a layout reference instead (of the form `R.layout.something`), otherwise the call to findViewById() with the spinner's id returns null, hence you get a `NullPointerException` on that line.

Comment: Thank you for this! I got it now. It helped me fix a few other bugs that we weren't going to address until the end, too! :)

Answer (score 0):

use setContentView(layoutid), (the layout id should have a spinner defined in it) before calling (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); spinner would be null until then which crashes your app

Answer (score 0):

Declare a xml call "my_xml_with_spinner.xml" in which you place a spinner view with id spinner1 inside a container(LinearLayout,RelativeLayout,etc...) then in your code change:

```
setContentView(textView)
```

for

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_with_spinner)
```

Now the spinner view will be found, when you call findViewById and spinner won't be null as it is now.

The reason because it is null is because you set as layout a simple TextView, and the code cannot find any view on the layout that you set (the textView) with id spinner1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This also helped me on a different part of code.